# Other-world manga story with an emotional mc

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manga had some chapters where the mc met a shy white haired elf while being kids, with her being bullied by others, after some chapters she becomes a guard of some noble, also the fmc was red haired and after some time she left the mc and cutted her hair, her leaving caused him to go on an emotional crisis.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Mostly black and white, but I remember the cover being coloured

Comment: Can you clarify the characters you mention? Is the protagonist male or female? Is the character that becomes the guard of a noble separate from the red-haired fmc? Who cuts their hair? Is it the main character that has an "emotional crisis"? And can you elaborate on the crisis? Is it just something like "girls should treasure their hair" and scolding her, or does more come from it?

Comment: The protagonist is a Male, the character that becomes a guard is the white haired elf, related to the crisis, I remember him going out questioning why did she left him and just leaving his sanity bit by bit, also the red-haired fmc left him because she wanted to become stronger by training somewhere else, at the moment she left she also left a letter with his recently cut hair

Comment: Wild guess: Sono Mono. Nochi ni. Hair colors match. Tagged "emotionally weak male lead". But I can't confirm if any of the specific events happen from just skimming through it.

Comment: I'm sorry but it wasn't :/, If I remember correctly that manga had over 50 chapters

Comment: Do you recall about when you read this? Any idea if this was complete or still ongoing? Do you know about where in the story these events occur? e.g. do you remember what happens in the first chapter? Do you remember any details about the setting of the manga, or anything else that might appear in a synopsis?

Comment: I read it like 1 year ago, but I don't remember what happened in the first chapter, I think it's still ongoing, besides that I don't know much else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this is *[Mushoku Tensei: Jobless Reincarnation](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/mushoku-tensei-jobless-reincarnation)*. It is licensed by [Seven Seas](https://sevenseasentertainment.com/series/mushoku-tensei-jobless-reincarnation/).

Chapter 4 includes the MC saving a young elf from being bullied. He initially thinks the elf is a boy, but is a girl. They become friends after he saves her.

[image: Elf]

Her hair is green, but in a black&white manga it can be hard to tell.

Chapter 51 would be the hair cutting scene:

[image: Waking up to cut hair]

After sleeping with the red-haired female lead, Eris, he wakes up to discover that she has cut off her hair and gone on a journey.

Comment: Can't confirm that the elf, Sylphiette, becomes a noble's guard or anything. That may have happened after I stopped reading.

Comment: Thankss man, maybe the miss on the elf hair messed up my search, you saved me lol

Comment: Just to flesh out the answer... Sylphiette's hair later turns white from green, and yes she does become one of three guards to a noble.